# openfiledialog getting data as multidimensional array with string split

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

i am reading a file from the openfiledialog. and it looks like this:

```
0001,pencil,planet office,0.05,1,20/n
0010,black pen,ribo,0.10,5,15/n
0011,blue pen,ribo,0.10,6,8/n
0012,red pen,ribo,0.12,8,3/n
1015,refill pad (lined),planet office,1.00,0,50/n
1016,refill pad (blank),pads are us,1.20,2,5/n
```

i want to put this information in a multidimensional array each row have 7 cols by using split method and this is my code and it is not working the error is "cannot implicitly convert type string to string[,]" i know that i am getting the data in an array not a multidimensional array but how can i read from the file as a multidimensional array with splitting each row from the comma.

```
  private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[,] Lines;
        //string[][] StringArray = null;
        //to get the browsed file and get sure it is not curropted
        try 
        {
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName))
                {
                    string[,] data;
                    while ((data = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Lines = data;                                     



                    }


                }
                FilePath.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
               //textBox1.Text += (string)File.ReadAllText(FilePath.Text);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ex) 
        {

            MessageBox.Show("there is an error" + ex+ "in the file please try again");
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer to one of your earlier questions for the same problem:
[use unassigned local variable 'multidimension'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669026/use-unassigned-local-variable-multidimension/7669130#7669130)

I've updated it make it a bit more complete:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    List<String> Lines = new List<String>();

    try 
    {
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName))
            {
                while ((data = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Lines.Add(data);
                }
            }
            FilePath.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ex) 
    {

        MessageBox.Show("there is an error" + ex+ "in the file please try again");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert array of arrays to multidimensional.
Use a list:

```
        List<string[]> data = new List<string[]>();
        string readFromReadLine;
        while ((readFromReadLine= sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            data.Add(readFromReadLine.Split(','));
        }
        string[,] lines = new string[data.Count,yourArrayLength];
        //convert array of arrays to multidimensional 
        for (int x=0;x<data.Count;x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < yourArrayLength; y++)
            {
                lines[x, y] = data[x][y];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

StreamReader.ReadLine has the return type of string and data is a string[,], so when you attempt to assign data = StreamReader.ReadLine it complains about the type mismatch.

```
                string[,] data;
                string readFromReadLine;
                while ((readFromReadLine= sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    data = readFromReadLine.Split(.....);             
                    //do other stuff here
                }
```

Comment: i did what you said i am getting an error on the data = readfromreadline.split(); cannot implicitly convert type string[] to string