# read file multidimensional array c# split

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [use unassigned local variable 'multidimension'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669026/use-unassigned-local-variable-multidimension)

I am getting an error when I run this program. what the code do is read from text file rows and sentences is separated from each other by a comma and what I did is split them and put them in multi-dimensional array but I am getting an error at run time which is:

```
"unhanded exception has occurred in your application if you click continue the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue if you click quit the application will close immediately"
```

Code:

```
try {
    DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK) {

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName)) {  
            string[] data= null;
            string ReadFromReadLine;
            ReadFromReadLine = sr.ReadLine();
            string[,] multidimensional = new string[ReadFromReadLine.Length, data.Length];

            while (ReadFromReadLine != null) {
                data = ReadFromReadLine.Split(',');

                for (int i = 0; i <= ReadFromReadLine.Length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j <= data.Length; j++ ) {
                        multidimensional[i, j] = data[j];
                    }
                }    
            }

            for(int i = 0 ; i<ReadFromReadLine.Length;i++) {
                for(int j = 1; j<= data.Length ; j++) {
                    textBox1.Text +=  multidimensional[i,j];
                }
            }
        }
        FilePath.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        //textBox1.Text += (string)File.ReadAllText(FilePath.Text);
    }
}
catch(IOException ex) {
    MessageBox.Show("there is an error" + ex+ "in the file please try again");
}
}
```

Comment: **What exception do you get**? _Use the debugger!_

Comment: @SLaks: this is his follow-up to [use unassigned local variable 'multidimension'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669026/use-unassigned-local-variable-multidimension). The debugging continues for four questions...so far.

Comment: You have posted three questions about this same issue. This answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669026/use-unassigned-local-variable-multidimension/7669130#7669130 contains the solution to your problem. The primary problem is that you're trying to build a multi-dimensional array when you don't know how many rows you have. His suggestion to use a `List<string[]>` is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

The error is here:

```
ReadFromReadLine = sr.ReadLine();
string[,] multidimensional = new string[ReadFromReadLine.Length, data.Length];
```

When end of file is encountered, `ReadLine()` returns `null`. Then the second line crashes because `ReadFromReadLine.Length` cannot be computed.